# Local preprocessing with Gulp, Stylus, and Browser-sync

Tags: gulp, mamp, browser-sync, gulp-stylus

I'm trying to setup CSS preprocessing and browser-sync for a client on windows. Prepros seems to be junk, and he can't use codeKit because it's Mac only.

I gave him these resources: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/supercharge-your-local-wordpress-development--cms-28303 and https://browsersync.io/docs/gulp

The preprocessing works great, but the browser has to be manually refreshed to see the CSS changes.

Can you spot what is incorrect in this code? MAMP is also involved... so it could be something else. I'm trying out different configurations to trouble-shoot.

```
// gulpfile.js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var stylus = require('gulp-stylus');

gulp.task('setup-server', function() {
  var files = [
    './style.css',
    './*.php',
  ];
  browserSync.init(files, {
    proxy: 'https://website-name.dev',
  });
});

gulp.task('compile-stylus', function () {
  return gulp.src('stylus/*.styl')
    .pipe( stylus({
      // options
    }))
    .pipe( gulp.dest('./') ) // root of theme
    .pipe( browserSync.stream() )
  ;
});

gulp.task('default', ['setup-server', 'compile-stylus'], function() {
  gulp.watch('stylus/**/*.styl', ['compile-stylus']);
});
```

file structure

```
project-root
  gulpfile.js
  /stylus
    /partials
    style.styl
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes:

```
var browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();
var reload = browserSync.reload;
```

and the following change at the end of the task:

```
gulp.task('compile-stylus', function () {
  return gulp.src('stylus/*.styl')
    .pipe( stylus({
      // options
    }))
    .pipe( gulp.dest('./') ) // root of theme
    .pipe( browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});
```

And I assume you meant gulpfile.js not gruntfile.js in your folder structure.

Comment: I did mean gulpfile.js ; ) I'll try that out!